# How to sort and search in JavaScript large set

Tags: javascript, sorting, search

The array "scores" tells the total points for each person involved in a contest. So for example:

```
User A: 100 points
User B: 90 points
User C: 90 points
User D: 80 points
User E: 75 points
User F: 60 points
```

According to above scores we will have this ranking:

```
User A: #1
User B: #2  
User C: #2
User D: #3
User E: #4
User F: #5
```

This ranking method follows the Dense Ranking method.

Then we have a user named alice. If she gets 55 points, she will rank at position #6 (according to ranking above).
If she scores 90 points, she will rank at position #2. And so on.

I actually have an array containing different "sessions" for alice. So having for example:
[55, 90]

This means that first time will alice be ranked at position #6. While second time she will be ranked at position #2.

I coded this, and it works. However, this does not seem to be very efficient. For large datasets, with half million entries in the scores-array, it times out. This is the code:

```
const getPosition = (element, scores) => {
    scores.push(element);
    scores.sort(function (a,b) { return b-a; });
    return scores.indexOf(element)+1;
}

function climbingLeaderboard(scores, alice) {
    var uniqueSet = new Set(scores);
    scores = [...uniqueSet];
    var positions = [];
    let aliceIndex = 0;
    while(aliceIndex < alice.length){
        positions.push(getPosition(alice[aliceIndex], scores));
        aliceIndex++;
    }
    return positions;
}

function main() {
    const scores = [100, 90, 90, 80, 75, 60];
    const alice = [50, 65, 77, 90, 102];
    let result = climbingLeaderboard(scores, alice);
    console.log(result.join("\n") + "\n");
}
```

I guess the "sort"-function and/or searching for the element in the array with indexOf is the problem. But I could not find a way to make these two operations more efficient.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: you don't need to search. Sort the arrays, then go from left to right, and whenever another value occurs, increase the rank by one. Assign the index to each entry.

Comment: @JonasWilms you mean from highest value in the alice list to lowest, correct?  And then searching through the scores from highest to lowest.  I think the only adjustment to your suggestion is that if alice happens to have a score that already exists in the scores, then there is no need to increase the rank by one.

Comment: @oderfla in a situation where you have half a million scores in the scores array, are the scores all still in a range of what appears to be integer values from 0 - 100?  Or when you scale to that size, do the scores also scale?  Ie, will you have a score of, say, 100,000 if you were to have half a million scores?

Comment: @JonTrent not sure I understand your question. But what most people seem to miss is that for each loop, I need to resort the array. Because the added value for Alice, each time, is only temporary. She will not be included again, the second time, and so on.  Regrading the range: well, the first entry I see in the scrores-array is "999997617". So I dont think there is any limit.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `getPosition` function to below and try. Just removed your sort function and doing the full array search with a condition.

```js
const getPosition = (element, scores) => {
    let length = scores.length;
    let rank = 1;
    for(let i=0; i<length; i++) {
        if(scores[i] > element) {
        rank++;
      }
    }
    return rank;
}
const scores = [100, 90, 90, 80, 75, 60];
const alice = [50, 65, 77, 90, 102];

console.log(getPosition(77, scores));
```

Comment: Thanks but it still fails timing out, exactly like mine.

Answer (score 1):

this approach assumes that in case of equal scores Alice should be place first in the score bracket
meaning if she scores 90 then she will be ranked 2nd, behind 100 but above the rest of the 90s

```
function calculatePositions(scores, aliceScores) {
  let positions = [];
  const uniqueScoresSet = new Set([...scores]);
  const uniqueScoresArray = Array.from(uniqueScoresSet);

aliceScores.forEach((aliceScore) => {
    let position = uniqueScoresArray.findIndex((score) => aliceScore >= score);
    position = position === -1 ? scores.length : position + 1;
    positions.push(position);
  });

  return positions;
}

function main() {
  const scores = [100, 90, 90, 80, 75, 60];
  const alice = [50, 65, 77, 90, 102];
  let result = calculatePositions(scores, alice);
  console.log(result.join("\n") + "\n");
}
```

this approach assumes that in case of equal scores Alice should be place last in the score bracket
meaning if she scores 90 then she will be ranked 4th, behind 100 and the two other 90s.

```
function calculatePositions(scores, aliceScores) {
  let positions = [];
  aliceScores.forEach((aliceScore) => {
    let position = scores.findIndex((score) => aliceScore > score);
    position = position === -1 ? scores.length : position + 1;
    positions.push(position);
  });

  return positions;
}

function main() {
  const scores = [100, 90, 90, 80, 75, 60];
  const alice = [50, 65, 77, 90, 102];
  let result = calculatePositions(scores, alice);
  console.log(result.join("\n") + "\n");
}
```

Comment: Thanks man. However, none of your solutions worked,. I mean, I got incorrect results. Did you try it?

Comment: @oderfla the first snippet produces [7,5,4,2,1] which is (to my understanding) a correct result. What output did you expect.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write expected output. However, this is what I was expecting: 6, 5, 4, 2, 1.
Also, when I run your code its output is: 7, 6, 5, 4, 1

Comment: @oderfla it was a bug in the case the score was to be placed at the last position. Please check again as I edited my answer (run the first snippet). The output is [6,5,4,2,1]

Comment: Im sorry. I tried both of them but none of them works. None of them passed the test :(

Comment: @oderfla out of curiousity, how many entries do the arrays have?

Answer (score 1):

Here's another take... Maybe not the most efficient method, but believe it does the trick.  This in effect is an implementation of Jonas Wilms' comment to the question.

This is somewhat of a brute force solution, as it walks the scores array for each of alice's scores.  A more efficient means would involve sorting alice's scores from highest to lowest (but keeping track of the original order in order to organize the results in the proper order), and then walking both the scores array and alice's array simultaneously.

Note that the solution below runs the test case from the question, in addition to running a test case against an array of 1M scores which is populated with random scores in the range from 99,999 to 0.

```js
function climbingLeaderboard(scores, alice) {
  scores.sort( (a, b) => b - a );
  aliceRank = [];
  for ( let aliceScore of alice ) {
    let scoreIndex = 0;
    let rank = 0;
    while ( scoreIndex < scores.length ) {
      if ( scoreIndex === 0 || scores[ scoreIndex - 1 ] !== scores[ scoreIndex ] ) {
        rank++;
      }
      if ( scores[ scoreIndex ] <= aliceScore ) {
        aliceRank.push( rank++ );
        break;
      }
      scoreIndex++;
    }
    if ( scoreIndex === scores.length ) {
      aliceRank.push( ++rank );
    }
  }
  return aliceRank;
}

function main() {
  const scores = [100, 90, 90, 80, 75, 60];
  const alice = [50, 65, 77, 90, 102];
  let result = climbingLeaderboard(scores, alice);
  console.log(result);
  
  console.log( 'Generating array of 1M scores' );
  let scores2 = new Array( 1000000 );
  for ( let i = 0; i < scores2.length; i++ ) {
    scores2[ i ] = Math.floor( 100000 * Math.random() );
  }
  alice2 = [50000, 65000, 77000, 90000, 102000, -1];
  let result2 = climbingLeaderboard(scores2, alice2);
  console.log( `First of the 1M scores is ${scores2[0]} and last score is ${scores2[999999]}` );
  console.log( result2 );
}

main();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. But still not working. It still times out :/

Comment: Hmmmm... you must have an issue with your environment.  On my workstation (Windows 10, Chrome 83.0.4103.97 Build 64-bit), this runs in less than 1s.

Answer (score 0):

Merged your function into one. returning rank as an object in the format `{ mark : rank}`

```
{
  102: 1,
  50: 50,
  65: 35,
  77: 23,
  90: 10
}
```

```js
function climbingLeaderboard(scores, alice) {
  scores = [...new Set(scores)];
  let length = scores.length;
  const rank = alice.reduce((obj, key) => {
    obj[key] = 1;
    return obj;
  }, {});
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    alice.forEach((item) => {
      if (scores[i] > item) {
        rank[item]++;
      }
    });
  }
  return rank;
}


const scores = [];
for (i = 0; i < 500000; i++) {
  scores[i] = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100);
}
const alice = [50, 65, 77, 90, 102];
let result = climbingLeaderboard(scores, alice);
console.log(result);
```